# sql query to divide a value over different records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following recordset:

```
1 1000  -1
2 500   2
3 1000 -1
4 500   3
5 500   2
6 1000 -1
7 500   1
```

So 3x a number 1000 with -1, total -3.

4x a number 500 with different values

Now I'm in need of a query which divides the sum of code 1000 over the 4 number 500 and removes code 1000. 
So the end result would look like:

```
1 500   1.25
2 500   2.25
3 500   1.25
4 500   0.25
```

The sum of code 1000 = -3
There's 4 times code 500 in the table over which -3 has to be divided.
-3/4 = -0.75

so the record "2 500 2" becomes "2 500 (2+ -0.75)" = 1.25

etc

As an SQL newbie I have no clue how to get this done, can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please explain how did you get to the end result? What mathematic operations do you need exactly?

Comment: so 1000 and 500 are keys to numbers which need this operation?  Or is it because the 1000 ones are negative and the 500 ones are positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Select col1,( 
(Select sum(col2 )
   from tab
  where col1 =1000)
  /
  (Select count(*) 
   from tab
   where col1 =500))+Col2 as new_value 
 From tab
 Where col1=500
```

Here tab, col1,col2 are table name, column with (1000 ,  500) value, column with (1,2,3 value)

Comment: so many mistakes.  You want sum(col3) and count for the 2nd sub-query.

Comment: Im going for this one it looks least complex, thanks

Comment: At least hogan should get more points. Without his help this one would be far from right.

Comment: @wumpz and my answer is actually more readable. Life is so unfair! :-)

Comment: @hogan ;) I think not but that does not count here anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CTEs to do it "step-wise" and build your solution.  Like this:

```
with sumup as
(
  select sum(colb) as s
  from table
  where cola = 1000
), countup as
(
  select count(*) as c
  from table
  where cola = 500
), change as
(
  select s / c as v 
  from sumup, countup
)
select cola, colb - v
from table, change
where cola = 500
```

Two things to note:

This might not be the fastest solution, but it is often close.

You can test this code easy, just change to final select statement to select the name of the CTE and see what it is.  For example this would be a good test if you are getting a bad result:

```
with sumup as
(
  select sum(colb) as s
  from table
  where cola = 1000
), countup as
(
  select count(*) as c
  from table
  where cola = 500
), change as
(
  select s / c as v 
  from sumup, countup
)
select * form change
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give the results you are after:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Number INT, Value INT)
INSERT @T (ID, Number, Value)
VALUES
    (1, 1000, -1),
    (2, 500, 2),
    (3, 1000, -1),
    (4, 500, 3),
    (5, 500, 2),
    (6, 1000,-1),
    (7, 500, 1);


SELECT  Number, Value, NewValue = Value + (x.Total / COUNT(*) OVER())
FROM    @T T
        CROSS JOIN 
        (   SELECT  Total = CAST(SUM(Value) AS FLOAT)
            FROM    @T
            WHERE   Number = 1000
        ) x
WHERE   T.Number = 500;
```

Inside the cross join we simply get the sum where the number is 1000, this could just as easily be done as a subselect:

```
SELECT  Number, Value, NewValue = Value + ((SELECT CAST(SUM(Value) AS FLOAT) FROM @T WHERE Number = 1000) / COUNT(*) OVER())
FROM    @T T
WHERE   T.Number = 500;
```

Or with a variable:

```
DECLARE @Total FLOAT = (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM @T WHERE Number = 1000);

SELECT  Number, Value, NewValue = Value + (@Total / COUNT(*) OVER())
FROM    @T T
WHERE   T.Number = 500;
```

Then using the analytic function `COUNT(*) OVER()` you can count the total number of results that are 500.

Answer (score 1):

And here is another solution:

```
select number1, value1, 
value1 
+ (select sum(value1) from table1 where number1=1000)/
  (select count(*) from table1 where number1=500) calc_value
from table1 where number1=500
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c68a0/1

I hope I got your question right. Then this is imho the best to read.